# Несоответствие типов

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Есть функция осуществляющая поворот геометрической фигуры вокруг заданной точки на заданный угол.

```
function rotation(edit3,edit4,edit5:tedit;image1:timage):boolean;
var xr,yr,ang,xtemp:real;
i:integer;
begin
  Image1.Picture:=nil;
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clred;
  xr:=StrToFloat(edit3.text);
  yr:=StrToFloat(edit4.text);
  ang:=StrToFloat(edit5.text);
  for i := 0 to k do
    begin
      if i=0 then
      begin
        xtemp:=xkoord[i];
        xkoord[i]:=abs(xr+(xkoord[i]-xr)*cos(ang)-(ykoord[i]-yr)*sin(ang));
        ykoord[i]:=abs(yr+(xtemp-xr)*sin(ang)+(ykoord[i]-yr)*cos(ang));
        Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(xkoord[i],ykoord[i]);
      end
      else
      begin
        xtemp:=xkoord[i];
        xkoord[i]:=xr+(xkoord[i]-xr)*cos(ang)-(ykoord[i]-yr)*sin(ang);
        ykoord[i]:=yr+(xtemp-xr)*sin(ang)+(ykoord[i]-yr)*cos(ang);
        Image1.Canvas.LineTo(xkoord[i],ykoord[i]);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

В строках

```
xkoord[i]:=abs(xr+(xkoord[i]-xr)*cos(ang)-(ykoord[i]-yr)*sin(ang));
     ykoord[i]:=abs(yr+(xtemp-xr)*sin(ang)+(ykoord[i]-yr)*cos(ang));
```

Компилятор нашел ошибку Incompatible types : "Integer" and "Extended".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xkoord[i]` - у вас скорее всего тип integer (в самой функции нет, он определяется выше, но судя по всему это массив координат точек), значит при вычислении надо приводить к целочисленному типу:

```
    xkoord[i]:=trunc(xr+(xkoord[i]-xr)*cos(ang)-(ykoord[i]-yr)*sin(ang));
    ykoord[i]:=trunc(yr+(xtemp-xr)*sin(ang)+(ykoord[i]-yr)*cos(ang));
```

Comment: Действительно. Я перепутал функции abs и trunc. Спасибо большое.

Comment: `trunc` просто отбрасывает дробную часть, правильнее использовать округление - `round`